# MVC2 ListBox not binding from View to Controller

Tags: c#, nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a many-to-many relationship in NHibernate, and I'm trying to bind all items in a Html.ListBoxFor() to my Model, but that list always comes with 0 items in the Model passed to Controller.

Here's what I've got so far:

Role.hbm.xml > 'left' side of many-to-many relationship

```
<bag name="LdapGroups" table="CADU_TB_ROLE_LDAP_OBJECTS" cascade="all">
    <key column="ID_ROLE" />
    <many-to-many  column="ID_LDAP_OBJECT" class="LdapObject" />
</bag>
```

Role.cs > Model

```
public class Role {
    public virtual IList<LdapObjects> LdapGroups {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

RoleController.cs > Controller

```
public class RoleController: Controller {
    public ActionResult Create(Role obj) {
        // Create logic here
        // here, obj.LdapGroups.Count is equal to 0, but instantiated
    }
}
```

Create.aspx > View (right list in image below)

```
<%= Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.LdapGroups,
    new List<CaduMVC.Models.LdapObject>()
        .Select(o => new SelectListItem() {
            Value = o.Id.ToString(),
            Text = o.Description
        }),
        new { id="lbSelectedGroups",
              @class = "form-control",
              style = "height: 120px;" }) %>
```

Here's the View (Items are passed from left to right using JQuery. Item type is *LdapObject*)

[image]

I need to get all items from *lbSelectedGroups* (right list) and put them in the *obj (obj.LdapGroups)* param (Create Action), but it comes with 0 items

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some debugging, I found that `Html.ListBoxFor()` method sends a collection of values ​​(`value` attribute from `option` tag), and not the `ListItem` objects (which I was expecting). 
I created a transient property in the Model object of type `int[]`, which receives that list of values, then create and insert the deattached objects into the list of LdapObjects. As follows:

Role.cs > Model

```
public class Role {
    public virtual IList<LdapObjects> LdapGroups {
        get;
        set;
    }
    // Transient
    public virtual int[] LdapGroupsSelected {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Create.aspx > View (right list in image above)

```
<%= Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.GruposLdapSelecionados,
    new Iesi.Collections.Generic.HashedSet<CaduMVC.Models
            .LdapObject>()
        .Select(o => new SelectListItem() {
            Value = o.Id.ToString(),
            Text = o.Descricao,
        }),
        new { id="lbGruposSelecionados",
            @class = "form-control",
            style = "height: 120px;" }) %>
```

RoleController.cs > Controller

```
public ActionResult Create(Role obj) {
    . . .
    for(int i = 0; i < obj.LdapGroupsSelected.Length; i++) {
        obj.LdapGroups.Add(new LdapObject(Convert.ToInt32(
                obj.LdapGroupsSelected[i])));
    }
    session.Merge(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At a first glance what i see is there is controller action missing when click on >> button. That action should get all items in the both lists via jquery get using a pattern and pass a collection of items to controller. The action will push items to second box and send the result. The jquery success method take data from collections and refill both List Boxes.

Comment: The >> button is ok. That button sends the selected item in the left list to the right list. What I need to do is get all items from the right list (previously selected in the left list) and bind that to the Model (which goes to the Action in Controller).
The `Create(Role obj)` does not receive the list in `obj.LdapGroups` (it comes null).